# Sphinx numbered list not being shown as a list

Tags: python-sphinx

I have the following Sphinx code in a .rst file in my doc/source directory:

```
Installing   
----------
1. Get hold of a Fortran 77 compiler for your platform. For Windows try Fort99 (http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~roumani/fortran/ftn.htm) or Cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/),
for OS X try the g77 compiler from the HPC Mac OSX project (http://hpc.sourceforge.net/) and for Linux you should be able to install g77 or equivalent from your package manager.
2. Install the compiler, move to the directory containing the 6S .f files and run ``make``
3. Check the resulting executable is working correctly by passing it one of the example input files, for example::
```

However, when I generate the documentation the numbered list appears without any line breaks between the items, as one long paragraph. The resulting HTML file can be seen at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/315580/introduction.html

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, or what I can do to stop it happening?

Comment: I can not see your example anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the line break after the comma in the first list item, it should work:

```
Installing
----------
1. Get hold of a Fortran 77 compiler for your platform. For Windows try Fort99 (http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~roumani/fortran/ftn.htm) or Cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/), for OS X try the g77 compiler from the HPC Mac OSX project (http://hpc.sourceforge.net/) and for Linux you should be able to install g77 or equivalent from your package manager.
2. Install the compiler, move to the directory containing the 6S .f files and run ``make``
3. Check the resulting executable is working correctly by passing it one of the example input files, for example::
```

You can also have multiline list items, like this:

```
Installing
----------
1. Get hold of a Fortran 77 compiler for your platform. 

   For Windows try Fort99 (http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~roumani/fortran/ftn.htm) or Cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/), for OS X try the g77 compiler from the HPC Mac OSX project (http://hpc.sourceforge.net/) and for Linux you should be able to install g77 or equivalent from your package manager.
2. Install the compiler, move to the directory containing the 6S .f files and run ``make``
3. Check the resulting executable is working correctly by passing it one of the example input files, for example::
```

Comment: also, don't forget that you can use automatically numbered lists with `#.` in place of `1.`,`2.` etc.